# Calculating mean of each column and reshaping

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a csv dataset for student of ID 229, where:

```
StudID            Score            Weight
 229                65               51
 229                45               43
 229                82               79
```

and I'm going to calculate the mean of score and weight of student, where I want to obtain as below:

```
Measurements   Mean Value   #Measurements and mean value are new column names

Score          64         #score and weight which used to be column names are now under measurements
Weight         57.67
```

So what i did so far is as below:

```
stud_data <- read.csv("student_weight.csv")
stud_mean <- colMeans(stud_data[2:3])    #finding the mean of only score and weight
```

which gives me the below when i print stud_mean:

```
Score               Weight
 64                  57.67
```

Is it possible to format output in a way i would obtain:

```
Measurements        Mean Value          #Measurements and Mean value are new column names

   Score                64
   Weight               57.67
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understood what you're trying to do. Are you asking how to aggregate multiple columns at once? Or is this about how to reshape your aggregate data?

Regarding the former, in base R you can do

```
aggregate(cbind(Score, Weight) ~ StudID, df, FUN = mean)
#  StudID Score   Weight
#1    229    64 57.66667
```

Regarding the latter, you can use `stack` to reshape

```
stack(aggregate(cbind(Score, Weight) ~ StudID, df, FUN = mean))
#     values    ind
#1 229.00000 StudID
#2  64.00000  Score
#3  57.66667 Weight
```

Here I assume your actual data contains data for more than one `StudID`, so you probably want to aggregate data by `StudID`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "StudID            Score            Weight
 229                65               51
 229                45               43
 229                82               79", header = T)
```

Comment: would aggregating based on StudID be stack(aggregate(cbind(Score,Weight), by=list(stud_data$StudID), df, FUN=mean)) in this case?

Comment: @Maxxx Just `stack(aggregate(cbind(Score,Weight) ~ StudID, df, FUN=mean))`, see the second part of my answer where I'm doing exactly that. I'm assuming that `StudID` is a column of your `data.frame`, as per your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a very short Wide-to-Long problem, and the easiest way is to use `tidyr::gather`:

```
data.frame('Score'=64, 'Weight'=57.67) %>%
    tidyr::gather('Measurements', 'Value')

  Measurements Value
1        Score 64.00
2       Weight 57.67
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `stack` after `colMeans`

```
stack(colMeans(df[2:3]))
#  values    ind
#1 64.00000  Score
#2 57.66667 Weight
```

To assign column name, we could use `setNames`

```
setNames(stack(colMeans(df[2:3])), c("Mean_Value", "Measurements"))

#    Mean_Value  Measurements
#1     64.00000        Score
#2     57.66667        Weight
```

Comment: would it be possible if it's Measurements first followed by Mean Value in the second answer?

Comment: @Maxxx It's just about rearranging the columns. You could do `setNames(stack(colMeans(df[2:3]))[2:1], c("Measurements", "Mean_Value"))` Or `setNames(stack(colMeans(df[2:3])), c("Mean_Value", "Measurements"))[2:1]`